# Application-to-Application communication through web sockets

Tags: java, jetty, websocket

I have some trouble getting application-to-application communication via web sockets (that is without a browser to work). Since this does not seem to be the most usual application of web sockets, I wonder if anybody has any experience doing this.

Why do I want to use web sockets?

Because of firewall issues I need to go through port 80/8080 (and I need to continue to handle some other HTTP communication, so I can't just use plain TCP/IP socket communication).

How did I try to make this work?

I'm using Jetty 8.0 both for the server and for the client. My server code:

```
public class WebSocketTestServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

    public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest arg0, String arg1) {
        return new TestWebSocket();
    }

    class TestWebSocket implements WebSocket, WebSocket.OnTextMessage
    {
         public void onClose(int arg0, String arg1) {   
         }

         public void onOpen(Connection arg0) {
         }

         public void onMessage(String messageText) {
         }

    }
}
```

My client code:

```
public class MyWebSocketClient{

    MyWebSocketClient() throws IOException
    {       
        WebSocketClientFactory factory = new WebSocketClientFactory();
        try {
            factory.start();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        WebSocketClient client = factory.newWebSocketClient();

        WebSocket.Connection connection = client.open(new URI("ws://myserver:8080/testws"), new WebSocket.OnTextMessage()
        {
             public void onOpen(Connection connection)
             {
             } 

             public void onClose(int closeCode, String message)
             {
             }

             public void onMessage(String data)
             {
             }
        }).get(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

     }
```

What problem do I see?

A ProtocolException

```
Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Bad response status 302 Found
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory$HandshakeConnection.closed(WebSocketClientFactory.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory$WebSocketClientSelector.endPointClosed(WebSocketClientFactory.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.destroyEndPoint(SelectorManager.java:948)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.doUpdateKey(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$1.run(SelectorManager.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try to add "/" at the end of your address in the client's code:

```
"ws://myserver:8080/testws/"
```

It just fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do something similar to allow WS calls to an embedded Jetty REST API...here's my echo test code (Jetty 7), HTH

```
public class myApiSocketServlet extends WebSocketServlet
{    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException ,IOException 
    {
        OutputStream responseBody = response.getOutputStream();
        responseBody.write("Socket API".getBytes());
        responseBody.close();
    }

    public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest request, String protocol)
    {
        return new APIWebSocket();
    }

    class APIWebSocket implements WebSocket, WebSocket.OnTextMessage
    {

        Connection connection; 

        @Override
        public void onClose(int arg0, String arg1)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(Connection c)
        {
            connection = c;     
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String msg)
        {
            try
            {
                this.connection.sendMessage("I received: " + msg);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```